# Cannot use sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, server

I made a Ubuntu Server 20.04 VM in Hyper-V and whenever I try to run sudo apt-get update I get the following return:

```
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57.7 kB]
Err:2 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
Err:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Fetched 57.7 kB in 32s (1,828 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to be.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm able to ping and I can also download docker images and use sudo apt-get update inside a docker container. So I assume I do have some sort of network connection?
Does anyone know what I did wrong or how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Edit:
I'm able to ping to 8.8.8.8 and be.archive.ubuntu.com as well!

Comment: your virtual machine has no network connection, check your settings

Comment: I'm able to ping and I can download docker images so I assume that means I have a network connection? Although I'm not sure, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? And yes, you must know.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I know if I'm behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Yes! I just tried and I'm able to ping 8.8.8.8.

Comment: `ping -c 4 be.archive.ubuntu.com`  Maybe DNS problem?

Comment: I can also ping to be.archive.ubuntu.com without any issue!

Comment: Please try another mirror. I oversaw `Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease` connection to  there is possible.

Comment: How can I try another mirror? I'm sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: Not familiar with docker. to change to main server `sudo sed -i s,//be.archive,//archive,g  /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a cause of Your firewall conflicting with your network proxy.They way firewall is configured (factory settings  in mind) is that it places stricter protocol on network traffic.When combined with a proxy, that takes your Ipv6 and sends it to a server bank, then to the target domain.

When a proxy(s) become overloaded, it causes a massive slowdown in traffic. 8.8.8.8 is Google's standard dock address, and is slow( at least when I  use it).The proxy you're using is likely the cause for DNS timeout. I would advise doing the following:

1.Check to see if your firewall is blocking a port

```
        sudo telnet google.com 80
```

2.If you recieve an error, simply go to the activities page to launch the firewall gui and unblock port 80.I would personally  disable the proxy via wifi settings or ethernet

3.If apt-get update is still not working, it may be due to the software  repositories.If you are tuned to recieved pre-releases, then you may have to remove those pre-release packages.

```
 sudo apt-remove [name of repository]
```

Then,go to Software and  Updates on Activities, uncheck Pre-Release.

I am New to answering and interacting  on this  site, so I sincerely  apologize  for any editing  mistakes.

I hope this helps, best of luck.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. I've tried unblocking port 80 because I got an error from the first command. However, after trying these changes I'm now somehow unable to even use SSH. So I don't really know what I did wrong. Thank you so much for replying though!

Comment: For SSH errors, verify that the host IP Address is correct for the droplet.Verify that your network supports that SSH block.Some internet providers may block port 22 or custom SSH ports.Also check to see that they are not set to a default policy of DROP, and the port is not added to allow connections.